# Joomla: get active menu item

Tags: php, menu, joomla

I'm trying to implement a custom menu in my joomla template. I added this line at the desired position in my `index.php`

```
<?php include(dirname(__FILE__).DS.'/navi.php'); ?>
```

the `navi.php` looks like this

```
<?php
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access');

$db = &JFactory::getDBO();

$query = "SELECT * FROM jos_menu WHERE menutype='mainmenu' AND published='1' AND sublevel='0' AND access='0' ORDER BY ordering ASC;";
$db->setQuery($query);
$navi = $db->loadAssocList();

$menu   = &JSite::getMenu();
$active = $menu->getActive();

foreach ($navi as $item) {
    if ($item['id'] == $active->id) {
        $open = ' class="open"';
    } else {
        $open = '';
    }
    echo '<li'.$open.'><a href="'.$item['link'].'">'.$item['name'].'</a></li>';
}

?>
```

The problem is that the `$active` variable only contains data when the frontpage is open. What's wrong with this code?

Thank you!

Comment: Unrelated but two pet peeves in the code: 1 - include is not a function - it doesn't need the brackets. 2 - You have hard coded the 'jos_' table prefix in your sql.  I realise this is probably entirely for your own use, but best to at least be aware of the issue.  Use #__ (hash and two underscores) instead of jos_ and let Joomla do the substitution for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the bug: you need a different method to determine the url of the menu item:

```
$url = JRoute::_($item['link'].'&Itemid='.$item['id']);
echo '<li'.$open.'><a href="'.$url.'">'.$item['name'].'</a></li>';
```

Thank you!